# Leaflet Clustering Marker Groups with grouped Circles

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to cluster some Markers that have Circles grouped with them.

The clustering works. But the Circles don't appear once zoomed in enough to display the Markers instead of clusters.

Example code:

```js
const lMap = L.map('map').setView([51.508, -0.128], 11);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(lMap);
const mainItems = [L.marker([51.508, -0.128]), L.marker([51.5, -0.14]), L.marker([51.51, -0.1])];
const subItems = [L.circle([51.508, -0.128], {
  color: '#38f',
  fillColor: '#38f',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  radius: 60
}), L.circle([51.5, -0.14], {
  color: '#38f',
  fillColor: '#38f',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  radius: 40
}), L.circle([51.51, -0.1], {
  color: '#38f',
  fillColor: '#38f',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  radius: 50
})];
const mainGroup = L.featureGroup(mainItems);
const subGroup = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mainGroup, subItems);

const mainCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
mainCluster.addLayer(mainGroup);
lMap.addLayer(mainCluster);
lMap.addLayer(subGroup);
```

If I remove the clustering, then Circles do appear:

```js
// const mainCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
// mainCluster.addLayer(mainGroup);
lMap.addLayer(mainGroup);
lMap.addLayer(subGroup);
```

Is what I'm attempting possible?
What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not explicit, Leaflet.markercluster has only [partial support](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#group-methods) of Layer Groups:

> Groups are not actually added into the MarkerClusterGroup, only their non-group child layers.

As such, when you add `subGroup` to the map, and it adds the `subItems` into `mainGroup`, this *does not* transitively result into adding them into `mainCluster` Marker Cluster Group (MCG).

IIUC, you would like to "decorate" your Markers with some Circles, but you cannot directly add them into the MCG, otherwise they would increase the count and trigger spiderfication; and you still want them to be shown or hidden accordingly with the Marker they decorate?

In that case, you have several workarounds, one of them being to have directly a custom icon that contains its own decoration, as suggested by [RobertHardy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76627603/5108796).

Another possible solution, closer to your original intention of using actual Circles for decoration, would be to [listen](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-on) to your Markers events being [added](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-layeradd) or [removed](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-layerremove) from the map (being handled by MCG for (un)clustering):

```js
map.on('layeradd', (e) => {
    mainItems.forEach((marker, index) => {
        if (e.layer === marker) {
            // Assumes subItems are in same order as mainItems
            map.addLayer(subItems[index]);
        }
    });
});

map.on('layerremove', (e) => {
    mainItems.forEach((marker, index) => {
        if (e.layer === marker) {
            // Assumes subItems are in same order as mainItems
            map.removeLayer(subItems[index]);
        }
    });
});
```

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/8XfhHuh3YU3ZlgtK?preview

---

Another solution, somehow more generic and robust, could be to create a special Marker that "knows" that it should come along with an associated decoration Layer when it is unclustered, and collects it back when clustered:

```js
// Variation of Leaflet Marker that comes along with an
// associated "decorationLayer" whenever it is added to the map,
// and goes away with it when removed.
// Typically useful when added to a MarkerClusterGroup,
// so that the decoration does not count, but still follows
// the Marker (un)clustering.
// Limitation: when spiderfied, decoration remains on original coordinates.
// Could be improved with custom setLagLng method?
L.Marker.Decorated = L.Marker.extend({
    options: {
        decorationLayer: null, // Could even be a Layer Group!
    },
    onAdd(map) {
        L.Marker.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);

        // If decoration has been provided, add it to the map as well
        this.options.decorationLayer?.addTo(map);
    },
    onRemove(map) {
        L.Marker.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);

        // If decoration has been provided, remove it from the map as well
        this.options.decorationLayer?.remove();
    },
});

const mainItems = [
    new L.Marker.Decorated([51.508, -0.128], {
        decorationLayer: L.circle([51.508, -0.128], {
            color: '#38f',
            fillColor: '#38f',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            radius: 500,
        }),
    }),
    // Etc.
];
```

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Utr7WC110oIzaATl?preview

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to show each marker within a circle combined with marker clustering then a simpler approach would be to define a [custom marker icon](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/). This would mean that you don't need to add separate circle items and you also don't need the leaflet subgroup plugin. One thing to note is that the custom icon needs to be a PNG (which is raster) as far as I can tell. So you might want to consider adding a [retina version](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon-iconretinaurl) as well.

Comment: Thanks
The problem with this solution is that each circle would be a dynamic size for each marker.
I will update the question to make that clearer.